# How to remove or delete .jpg and .dpx image files in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on C++ project for GUI in MFC application on Visual studio 2015. I have an issue after generation of a .jpg and .dpx image files. 
Issue: First time, i can able to generate two .jpg files and two .dpx files but when i try to regenerate it again, it is generated but the timestamp is not updated which remains same. To solve this, i want to delete the existing file when i want to write it again.

Please anyone help me on this.
Thanks.

I have already tried with `remove(filename);`

```
remove("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\images\\splitleftImage_4K00.jpg");
remove("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\images\\splitleftImage_4K01.jpg");
remove("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\images\\Image_4K.dpx");

ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), _T("open"), _T("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\images\\magick.exe"), _T(" Image_4K.jpg -crop 50%x100% +repage splitleftImage_4K\%02d.jpg"), _T("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\images\\"), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), _T("open"), _T("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\images\\convert.exe"), _T(" Image_4K.jpg Image_4K.dpx"), _T("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\images\\"), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I want to see two .jpg and two .dpx image files after generating it each time.

Comment: Same way you 'remove or delete' any other file. C++ doesn't care, or the operating system either,

Comment: Every file has 3 date/times: Created, Modified, and Accessed. Which one do you mean by "timestamp"? The "modified" time should be updated, but "created" may not be updated. (that depends on the way those programs create images.)

Comment: `remove` is the correct way. If it not working for you then you should be investigating why, not trying some other method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I solved this issue by creating a new folder and place image on that folder and tried. Now it is updated the created time properly.